# How to display images neatly with tooltip of ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I want to display the image with the tooltip of ngx-bootstrap.

#### problem

- The width of the tooltip is insufficient and the image protrudes.
- The display position for the first time is different from the display position for the second and subsequent times.

1st
[image]

2nd
[image]

Is there a way to improve it?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsr9as)

- Angular CLI: 8.3.19
- Node: 12.12.0
- OS: darwin x64
- Angular: 8.2.14
- bootstrap: "^4.3.1"
- ngx-bootstrap: "^5.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by setting width of img tag like below.

```
<img id="tool-tip" src="https://placehold.jp/200x200.png"/>

#tool-tip {
  width: 180px;
}
```

So that it always lies within the tooltip neatly.
Here is the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pazo79